# Chaining path-dependent types and instantiating them when they having different parameter lists in Scala

Tags: scala, shapeless, dependent-type, path-dependent-type

I'm experimenting with writing more statically type-safe code by implementing a simple card game. In this game, there are several unique cards and each card has a card-specific effect which may require additional parameters (e.g., a target for the effect). A player holds two cards and on their turn chooses to play one of them, causing that card's effect to take place.

*Note: most of the details in this post are from trying it out in the REPL. I have a less statically type-safe implementation written but I want to make sure that what I want is feasible before diving completely into it.*

Here are some relevant definitions:

```scala
trait CardEffectParams
case class OneTarget(player: Player) extends CardEffectParams
case class TwoTargets(player1: Player, player2: Player) extends CardEffectParams
// ...

trait Card {
  // the parameters to use are specific to the card
  type Params <: CardEffectParams
}

trait Hand {
  case class CardInHand(card: Card) { /* with ctor not accessible from outside */ }
  // a player can hold two cards
  val card1: CardInHand
  val card2: CardInHand
}
```

I want to delegate the choosing of which card to play to some strategy so I can see how different strategies compare. This is where I'm stuck: I want to limit the cards you can return to the ones in the `Hand` object passed in the parameters, which I can do by typing it as `hand.CardInHand`:

```scala
trait Strategy {
  def choose(hand: Hand, gameState: GameState): hand.CardsInHand
}
```

But I also want to pass extra parameters: for example, one card might allow me to target just one player (e.g., skip their turn), but another might let me target two (e.g., swap their cards). These are modelled by `CardEffectParams`. So I want to return both `hand.CardsInHand` and a `cardInHand.card.Params` where `cardInHand` is the instance I'm returning, something like this:

```scala
/* NOT valid scala */
trait Strategy {
  def choose(hand: Hand, gameState: GameState): (c: hand.CardsInHand, c.card.Params)
}
```

So the first question is, can this be done? How would you represent this relationship?

I'm also stuck on how to instantiate the `CardEffectParams` subclasses, since each one may have different parameter lists. My first thought is to do a pattern match, but this fails because the type of the match block is the common ancestor of all possible results:

```scala
case object CardA extends Card {
  type Params = OneTarget
}
case object CardB extends Card {
  type Params = TwoTargets
}

object RandomStrategy extends Strategy {
  def choose(hand: Hand, gameState: GameState) = {
    val card: Card = /* randomly pick card1 or card2 */
    /* the type of the match block is CardEffectParams, not card.Params */
    val param: card.Params = card match {
      case CardA => OneTarget(...)
      case CardB => TwoTargets(...)
    }
  }
}
```

My current idea is to define a factory method within each card object that takes an hlist of arguments from which it produces the correct type:

```scala
trait Card {
  type Params <: CardEffectParams
  type HListTypeOfParams = /* insert shapeless magic */
  def create[L <: HListTypeOfParams](l: L): Params
}
```

from which I can then do the following?

```scala
// no idea if this works or not
val card: Card = ...
val params: card.Params = card match {
  case c: CardA => c.create(1 :: HNil)
  case c: CardB => c.create(1 :: 2 :: HNil)
}
```

But I feel like I've gone too far down the rabbit hole. Is what I want to achieve possible? Is it necessary? Do I need to dive so deep into typing to ensure static type safety or am I missing something really elementary?

Comment: Short answer: It is probably possible, but a pain. I'm working out how you can make this work. Expect it to be ugly.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, I would replace your tuple with a type that represents the relationship

```
trait CardAndParams {
    type C <: Card
    val card: C
    val params: C#Params
}

def choose[R <: CardAndParams](hand: Hand, gameState: GameState)(
    implicit helper: Helper {type Out = R}): R
```

You will need to use implicits like my `Helper` example to drive the actual strategy implementations and ensure the correct R is inferred. This is also the more usual way to do type-level computation:

```
sealed trait RandomStrategyHelper[C <: Card] {
    def params(): C#Params
}
object RandomStrategyHelper {
    implicit def forCardA = new RandomStrategyHelper[CardA] {
        def params() = 1 :: HNil
    }
    implicit def forCardB = new RandomStrategyHelper[CardB] {
        def params() = 1 :: 2 :: HNil
    }
}

def randomParams[C <: Card](card: C)(implicit rsh: RandomStrategyHelper[C]) =
    rsh.params()
```

But I guess you need a way to move from your randomly-generated card to a strongly typed one, and for that the pattern match seems appropriate, since it would be difficult to represent a random card at type level.

In general this kind of type-level programming is possible but hard in Scala - the language wasn't really designed for it. If you want to push this as far as it will go you may be better off using something like Idris.